# Dynamically add and hiding textViews

Tags: android, textview

I've got "for each" loop that creates textView for every obiect from the list and add them to the linear layout. It works great. Then I want to hide all of the textViews when user clicks on toggle button but here I've got problem - only the last textView from the list is being hidden , rest of them is still visible. I tried to solve this problem with many solutions ( for example with getChild()), but nothing works.

```
final List<FilterItem> filterItemList = filterData.getFilterItemList();
for (FilterItem filterItem : filterItemList) {
    final TextView filter = new TextView(MainPanelActivity.this);
    filter.setText(filterItem.getFilterItemName());
    filter.setTextColor(R.color.black);
    linearLayout.addView(filter);
    filter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textLine.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                       filter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                       filter.setVisibility(View.GONE);             
                    }
                }
    });
```

Comment: filter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); will give you reference of the last text view. that is why it will hide last textview only

Comment: Not exactly :) I use it like this in another part of the app and works fine - hides every TextView :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that youre setting a listener for `textLine` inside the for loop - so for each iteration you set a new listener that changes the visibility of the `TextView` created in the current iteraton.

Move `textLine.setOnCheckedChangeListener()` outside of the for loop; and inside `onCheckedChanged` - loop through all children of `linearLayout` and set the visibility for each child.

```
textLine.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    for (View v : linearLayout.getChildren()) {
                        if (v instanceof TextView) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } else {
                                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);                
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks but that solution will hide also ToggleButtons (they are also inside this layout) and I don't want to do it :)

Comment: Thanks bro, that's what I needed ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a list of TextViews when you create them. Then set the click listener outside the for-loop as Dmitri says, which would iterate through the list of TextViews and set the visibility to GONE.

```
private void setup() {
    List<View> textViews = new ArrayList<>();
    for (FilterItem filterItem : filterData.getFilterItemList()) {
        View view = createTextViewFor(filterItem);
        linearLayout.addView(filter);

        textViews.add(view);
    }

    updateVisibility(textViews, View.GONE);

    textLine.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int visibility = isChecked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
                    updateVisibility(textViews, visibility);
                }
            }
    );
}

private View createTextViewFor(FilterItem filterItem) {
    TextView view = new TextView(MainPanelActivity.this);
    view.setText(filterItem.getFilterItemName());
    view.setTextColor(R.color.black);
    view.addFilter(filterItem);
    return view;
}

private void updateVisibility(List<View> views, int visibility) {
    for (View view : views) {
        view.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to display `textView` dynamically, I think putting `textView` inside `RecyclerView` will be a better idea. `RecyclerView` has its own `Adapter` which will make it easy to play with data and `textViews`. Give `recyclerView` a try. `RecycerView` for what you are trying to do can be learnt in few hours and sky is the limit for what you can do with `recyclerView` :)